# personality traits for a character

Tags: character-creation

I am looking for a big list of character personality traits that work well on PCs.

Some examples of such traits would be:

- "a deal is a deal is a deal": once commited to a deal, does not go back
- inventor: wants to try new ways of doing things
- social enterpreneur: as inventor, to social problems.
- hedonistic: mostly wants confort and pleasures
- pragmatical
- "fears death": will do anything to stay alive

I am quite sure such lists exist (maybe even on this site!) but could not manage to find them

---

Note: it would probably be impractical to post a list like that on site. But maybe there are some links to resources that might be useful.

I have seen once a book for computer game designers that had many such lists (but now I don't recall its name). The resources need not be focused in tabletop RPGs to be useful in the context of RPGs

Resources from RPGs might also be nice. For example, the rules for Vices and Virtues on 'The God Machine', plus the suggested vices and virtues, give good ideas for personality traits

Comment: I'd suggest a simple Google search on "personality traits list". The first two hits already give quite a lot to play with.

Comment: Maybe if you were asking for a particular system we could weigh in with real answers but as it stands this is too broad.

Comment: I don't think system is relevant, nor is it too broad.  I have some ideas for an answer, when I've got time to hit my bookshelf and sift some of my resources.

Comment: I got nothin'.  I thought a book I had would answer this question, but it's not quite what the OP is asking for, and I don't have any concise web sources.

Comment: @leokhorn: you are right. Your query already came up with a decent list that fits the bill. Mine were a bit less sucessful

Comment: @JoshuaAslanSmith. I am looking for sources that have big lists of personality traits that might be used to build a PC. I don't understand how it is too broad. The question is narrow and specific, what might be broad are the lists (and, then again, that is the point!)

Comment: The answers being too broad is part of the problem. Quoting from the close explanation below: "There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format."